# Problems while running the alexa helloWorldSample

Tags: java, maven, alexa-skills-kit

I try to deploy the alexa helloworld skill on my own Server using this [tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/deploy-a-sample-skill-as-a-web-service.html#h2_build_cmdline)

I can build the Sample and get 2 jar files in the target directory but when i try to run the Server via

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.executable=”java” -DdisableRequestSignatureCheck=true`

i get this error:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Launcher`

Can anyone help me in this case?

Best regards, 
FelixT

Here is my logfile with the error:

```
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <arguments>${exec.arguments}</arguments>
  <classpathScope default-value="runtime">${exec.classpathScope}</classpathScope>
  <cleanupDaemonThreads>${exec.cleanupDaemonThreads} default-value=</cleanupDaemonThreads>
  <commandlineArgs>${exec.args}</commandlineArgs>
  <daemonThreadJoinTimeout default-value="15000">${exec.daemonThreadJoinTimeout}</daemonThreadJoinTimeout>
  <includePluginDependencies default-value="false">${exec.includePluginDependencies}</includePluginDependencies>
  <includeProjectDependencies default-value="true">${exec.includeProjectDependencies}</includeProjectDependencies>
  <keepAlive default-value="false">${exec.keepAlive}</keepAlive>
  <killAfter default-value="-1">${exec.killAfter}</killAfter>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <mainClass>Launcher</mainClass>
  <pluginDependencies default-value="${plugin.artifacts}"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${skip}</skip>
  <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
  <stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads>${exec.stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads} default-value=</stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads>
  <systemProperties>
    <systemProperty>
      <key>javax.net.ssl.keyStore</key>
      <value>/root/java-keystore.jks</value>
    </systemProperty>
    <systemProperty>
      <key>javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword</key>
      <value>XXXXXXXXXX</value>
    </systemProperty>
    <systemProperty>
      <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.disableRequestSignatureCheck</key>
      <value>true</value>
    </systemProperty>
    <systemProperty>
      <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.supportedApplicationIds</key>
      <value>${supportedApplicationIds}</value>
    </systemProperty>
    <systemProperty>
      <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.timestampTolerance</key>
      <value>${timestampTolerance}</value>
    </systemProperty>
  </systemProperties>
  <testSourceRoot>${testSourceRoot}</testSourceRoot>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ helloworld >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ helloworld <<<
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata joda-time:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml in local (/root/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Failure to find joda-time:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml in file:///root/samples/skill-samples-java-master/helloworld/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of alexa-skills-kit-repo has elapsed or updates are forced
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for joda-time:joda-time/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] alexa-skills-kit-samples:helloworld:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]    com.amazon.alexa:alexa-skills-kit:jar:1.6.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile
[DEBUG]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]    com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]    com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.9.40:compile
[DEBUG]       com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.9.40:compile
[DEBUG]          com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.9.40:compile
[DEBUG]       com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.9.40:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.4:compile
[DEBUG]             org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]             commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[DEBUG]          com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]             com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]          joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ helloworld ---
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
[DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:test (scope managed from compile) (version managed from 3.8.1)
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: junit:junit:jar:3.8.2
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a14482]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = []
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathScope = runtime
[DEBUG]   (f) cleanupDaemonThreads = false
[DEBUG]   (f) daemonThreadJoinTimeout = 15000
[DEBUG]   (f) includePluginDependencies = false
[DEBUG]   (f) includeProjectDependencies = true
[DEBUG]   (f) keepAlive = false
[DEBUG]   (f) killAfter = -1
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =        id: local
      url: file:///root/.m2/repository/
   layout: none

[DEBUG]   (f) mainClass = Launcher
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginDependencies = [org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.2.1:, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile, org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: alexa-skills-kit-samples:helloworld:1.0 @ /root/samples/skill-samples-java-master/helloworld/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [       id: alexa-skills-kit-repo
      url: file:///root/samples/skill-samples-java-master/helloworld/repo
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
,        id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads = false
[DEBUG]   (s) key = javax.net.ssl.keyStore
[DEBUG]   (s) value = /root/java-keystore.jks
[DEBUG]   (s) key = javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
[DEBUG]   (s) value = Felix123
[DEBUG]   (s) key = com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.disableRequestSignatureCheck
[DEBUG]   (s) value = true
[DEBUG]   (s) key = com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.supportedApplicationIds
[DEBUG]   (s) key = com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.timestampTolerance
[DEBUG]   (f) systemProperties = [org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Property@7b159b, org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Property@5d9a50, org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Property@957c0f, org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Property@13a5f75, org.codehaus.mojo.exec.Property@1cb4004]
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Invoking : Launcher.main()
[DEBUG] Plugin Dependencies will be excluded.
[DEBUG] Project Dependencies will be included.
[DEBUG] Collected project artifacts [com.amazon.alexa:alexa-skills-kit:jar:1.6.0:compile, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile, org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.0.6.v20130930:compile, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10:compile, org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile, org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:jar:2.4:compile, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile, com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:jar:1.0.0:compile, com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j:jar:1.0.0:compile, com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.9.40:compile, com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.9.40:compile, com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.9.40:compile, com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.9.40:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.4:compile, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2:compile, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.2:compile, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile]
[DEBUG] Collected project classpath [/root/samples/skill-samples-java-master/helloworld/target/classes]
[DEBUG] Adding to classpath : file:/root/samples/skill-samples-java-master/helloworld/target/classes/
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: alexa-skills-kit to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jetty-server to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: javax.servlet to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jetty-http to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jetty-util to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jetty-io to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jetty-servlet to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jetty-security to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: log4j to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: slf4j-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: slf4j-log4j12 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-lang3 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: org.apache.commons.io to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-io to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: aws-lambda-java-core to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: aws-lambda-java-log4j to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: aws-java-sdk-dynamodb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: aws-java-sdk-s3 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: aws-java-sdk-kms to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: aws-java-sdk-core to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-logging to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: httpclient to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: httpcore to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-codec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jackson-databind to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jackson-annotations to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jackson-core to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: joda-time to classpath
[DEBUG] joining on thread Thread[Launcher.main(),5,Launcher]
[WARNING] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Launcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:46.627s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 27 19:09:37 UTC 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project helloworld: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Launcher -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project helloworld: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Launcher
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Launcher
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Launcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

and the Pom.xml: 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      4.0.0
      alexa-skills-kit-samples
      helloworld
      jar
      1.0
      helloworld
      http://developer.amazon.com/ask

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>alexa-skills-kit-repo</id>
      <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
      <artifactId>alexa-skills-kit</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.40</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <property name="disableRequestSignatureCheck" value="false"/>
    <property name="supportedApplicationIds" value=""/>
    <property name="timestampTolerance" value="150"/>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>Launcher</mainClass>
            <systemProperties>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>javax.net.ssl.keyStore</key>
                <value>/root/java-keystore.jks</value>
              </systemProperty>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword</key>
                <value>Felix123</value>
              </systemProperty>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.disableRequestSignatureCheck</key>
                <value>${disableRequestSignatureCheck}</value>
              </systemProperty>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.supportedApplicationIds</key>
                <value>${supportedApplicationIds}</value>
              </systemProperty>
              <systemProperty>
                <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.timestampTolerance</key>
                <value>${timestampTolerance}</value>
              </systemProperty>
            </systemProperties>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Would you please paste the contents of the `pom.xml` file in your `samples/` folder?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using Lambda or another HTTP call?

Comment: I try this on my own Server

Comment: I post my pom.xml now. To do that, i had to reduce my logfile caused by the caracter limitation in Stackoverflow. If it is needed, let me know